# Ubuntu 13.10\14.04\14.10 wireless problem

Tags: wireless, networking, lenovo, ideapad

I'm having problems with wireless in Ubuntu 13.10\14.04\14.10, sometimes when i start-up my laptop i can't find my WiFi and after i restart it works just fine but after sometime it drops the connection automatically and the Wifi disappear again. what can i do?!! i'm using lenovo z580.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 24 Dec 2014 09:36 EET +0200

Booted last: 24 Dec 2014 09:21 EET +0200

Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
Codename:   utopic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.16.0-29-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 15 22:27:29 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3975]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 [8086:0891] (rev c4)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2200 BGN [8086:4222]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04ca:2003 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 5986:0295 Acer, Inc 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

iwldvm                236430  0 
mac80211              660592  1 iwldvm
iwlwifi               183038  1 iwldvm
cfg80211              510218  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
mxm_wmi                13021  1 nouveau
wmi                    19193  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau
ideapad_laptop         18278  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 ideapad_laptop

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.7  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9e4e:36ff:fe65:3cf8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13401 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11357 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8517938 (8.5 MB)  TX bytes:1541178 (1.5 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"TE-Data"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.427 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'TE-Data' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:58   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### nm-tool ###########################

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [TE-Data] -----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           54 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    alalmeia:        Infra, <MAC 'alalmeia' [AC4]>, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 45 WPA WPA2
    TE Data:         Infra, <MAC 'TE Data' [AC2]>, Freq 2417 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WPA WPA2
    p-technology:    Infra, <MAC 'p-technology' [AC6]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 22 WPA WPA2
    *TE-Data:        Infra, <MAC 'TE-Data' [AC1]>, Freq 2427 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 73 WPA WPA2
    My Computer:     Infra, <MAC 'My Computer' [AC3]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 15 WPA WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.7
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TE-Data]] (600 root)
[connection] id=TE-Data | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=TE-Data | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Africa/Cairo (based on set time zone)

country EG: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 20), (N/A, 20)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 20), (N/A, 20), DFS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)

##### iwlist scan #######################

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'TE-Data' [AC1]>
                    Channel:4
                    Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
                    Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"TE-Data"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000019eba8fd49
                    Extra: Last beacon: 60ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'TE Data' [AC2]>
                    Channel:2
                    Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
                    Quality=22/70  Signal level=-88 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"TE Data"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000019ebe4b6ca
                    Extra: Last beacon: 60ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'My Computer' [AC3]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=20/70  Signal level=-90 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"My Computer"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000010eabdf33d5
                    Extra: Last beacon: 60ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC 'alalmeia' [AC4]>
                    Channel:9
                    Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                    Quality=33/70  Signal level=-77 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"alalmeia"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000015871e8199d
                    Extra: Last beacon: 60ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC 'TE-Data' [AC5]>
                    Channel:9
                    Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                    Quality=23/70  Signal level=-87 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"TE-Data"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000015871373164
                    Extra: Last beacon: 724ms ago
          lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 06 - Address: <MAC 'p-technology' [AC6]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=21/70  Signal level=-89 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"p-technology"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000206da914b
                    Extra: Last beacon: 100ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[iwldvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/iwldvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     092C5F7885F1C7B9B99605B
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-29-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        70:63:7F:DE:89:46:26:78:AF:F2:D9:C2:BB:12:90:BE:2F:ED:1F:B1
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-29-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     B3A65EB1DAE59CB6B5FD971
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-29-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        70:63:7F:DE:89:46:26:78:AF:F2:D9:C2:BB:12:90:BE:2F:ED:1F:B1
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-8.ucode
srcversion:     D335B9FC08B25C4ADA0BD33
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-29-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        70:63:7F:DE:89:46:26:78:AF:F2:D9:C2:BB:12:90:BE:2F:ED:1F:B1
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (defualt: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable (default: 1) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-29-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     DEE8EAA48495E392CD51C2D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-29-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        70:63:7F:DE:89:46:26:78:AF:F2:D9:C2:BB:12:90:BE:2F:ED:1F:B1
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: N
wd_disable: 1

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/libow-2.8-15.conf]
blacklist ds9490r
blacklist ds2490
blacklist wire

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf]
options cirrus modeset=1
options mgag200 modeset=1

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8136 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x8086:0x0891 (iwlwifi)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   17.357019] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   17.364681] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x0-0x0
[   17.606463] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   17.614110] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x0-0x0
[   17.682769] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   18.338388] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'TE-Data' [AC1]>
[   18.346333] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'TE-Data' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   18.348691] wlan0: authenticated
[   18.348793] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[   18.349344] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'TE-Data' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   18.352095] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'TE-Data' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[   18.354372] wlan0: associated
[   18.354396] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be issue with the power off manager, so please try the below command and check,

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

If so try with disabling the debug driver by using the following,

```
modprobe -r iwlwifi && modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Comment: i tried this before it is not working